# jquery show/hide div default show all

Tags: jquery

right now the code below works perfect but I want to default show all room divs. how would I do that?

**HTML:**

```
<select id="room_type">
    <option value="">-- Type --</option>
    <option value="oneroom">One room</option>
    <option value="tworoom">Two room</option>
</select>

<div id="oneroom" style="display:none">
    CONTENT 1
</div>
<div id="tworoom" style="display:none">
    CONTENT 2
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function ($) {
    $('#room_type').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val(),
            div = $('#' + location);
        $("div[id$='room']").hide();
        div.show();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Get rid of the `style="display:none"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either get rid of the `style="display:none"` on your divs, or add this jQuery before your change event handler: `$('div').show();`

Answer (score 1):

Look this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCANk/11/)

Code:

```
(function ($) {

    $("#oneroom, #tworoom").show(); // <-- This

    $('#room_type').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val(),
            div = $('#' + location);
        $("div[id$='room']").hide();
        div.show();
    });
})(jQuery);
```